# Delete files in a folder based on not being in a List.txt

Tags: windows-10, script, powershell-5.0

Objective:
Delete audio files in a folder that are not listed in the List.txt file

Reading the List.txt to compare with the files in the audio folder and deleting the files that are not listed in the list.

List.txt contents:

```
05 - Earth Wind and Fire - September (The Reflex Revision).mp3
Electric Light Orchestra - Last Train To London (Bootleg Extended Dance Remix).flac
120 - Kool & The Gang - Get Down On It (Soul Funk House Remix).wav
```

```
$files = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\List Audio Files for Normalization.txt"
$location = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\LUFS Audios\"

Get-Content $files | % {               
    $result = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "$location*$_*" 
    If(!$result) {
       Remove-Item $location* $result.Fullname
    }
}
```

In the Remove command, the message appears:
`Cannot bind argument to 'Path' parameter because it is null`

What is the command to remove the file from the audio folder, when the value  `!$Result` is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PowerShell: Delete all files except those in a list

Below are two PowerShell variations that work for this task as you describe which I've confirmed on my side emulating as much as possible based on the detail you provided.

### PowerShell 1

```
$files = Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\List Audio Files for Normalization.txt";
$location = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\LUFS Audios\";
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $location -File -Exclude $files | Remove-Item;
```

### PowerShell 2

```
$files = Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\List Audio Files for Normalization.txt";
$location = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\LUFS Audios\";
             
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $location -File | %{
    If($_.Name -notin $files ){ Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Force; };
    };
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [About Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2)

  `-notin` - value is not in a collection
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)

Comment: Get-content made all the difference... now both scripts work ok!